# Rails form_for with checkboxes, assign values to array-type variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, postgresql, checkbox

Rails 4.1.4, Ruby 2.1.2. Postgres.

I have a user model which has a `roles` attribute. The roles attribute is a postgres array type. I am trying to create a form with checkboxes of different role options, and a user can select which roles they fit into. If they select the 'director' checkbox, their `roles` attribute, now you should see:

`@user.roles = ['director']`.

I am trying to use a form_for, but maybe this is not possible.

Does anyone know how to do this?

```
form_for(@user) do |f|
    f.check_box :roles ...?
```

Comment: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes

Comment: How you get the collection object of all roles for user to choose?

Answer (score 1):

```
form_for(@user) do |f|
  f.check_box :roles, User::ROLES #assuming you have a constant ROLES holding your roles.
```

editing due to comment

Comment: How would I do this with roles that are not active record objects? They are simply strings (i.e. I simply want to add the string 'director' or 'admin' to the roles array if that check box is selected). I don't think I understand how to set up a User::ROLES constant that responds to an :id method.

Comment: do you want to be able keep few roles in :role attribute, right? You can do f.check_box :roles, User::ROLES, {multiple: true }

Comment: Rails error: `wrong number of arguments (2 for 4..6)`. No, simply strings within an array.

Comment: do you have this ROLES constant in User model?

Comment: probably `@user.roles`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
 form_for(@user) do |f|
   f.collection_check_boxes(:roles, @user.roles, :id, :labeling_method )
```

more details

http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes

Comment: Seems you miss the third parameter , it should be a collection object of all roles.

Comment: Nope I did `@user.roles` ...it is form object ......so as you told `collection_check_boxes(:post, :author_ids, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial)` but here `form_for` with form object `f` so `f.collection_check_boxes :author_ids, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial` refer http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes

Comment: Ok! I'm wrong. But still a suggestion use some other roles collectioin instead of  @user.roles. There will be no check_box displayed for  a new user.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion yes it should be good yes I can do but please see the question he already use `@user.roles` I thought it will be better to understand for him

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have some string constant in your User

```
<%= form.collection_check_boxes(:roles, USER::ROLES_STRINGS[access_if_you_need_from_this_constant_but_we_need_an_array_here].keys, :to_s, Proc.new{|l| USER::ROLE_STRINGS[access_if_you_need_from_this_constant_but_we_need_an_array_here][l]}) %>
```

Should work / get you close based on your structure!